# Where can I find the number of records for a specific entity in new CloudKit Dashboard?

Tags: icloud, dashboard

In the previous version of Dashboard I was able to preview how many records were created by users of my app. But in the new dashboard, there is no info about the number of created addresses in the database. It was very useful to me.

Did I miss it, or was it dropped by Apple?

[image]